# Handling email forwards for Reply Mail Management within Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, campaign, reply-mail-management

We have a specific use case where we are facing a challenge with campaign email forwarding.

We are trying to capture email replies inside sfmc. Let's say a campaign email goes out to a customer from SFMC. The customer replies to that email. Currently we have enabled Reply Mail Management (RMM) that allows us to capture this direct email reply, and we are able to process the response and use it for our custom logic. In our case, we use that response to begin creating a lead. We stitch some other data to the info extracted from this response and go on to generate our lead. As of now, RMM allows ONLY direct replies to be captured, because when the recipient responds to their campaign email, the To-address generated contains a unique string that routes the reply to SFMC (in simple words). But here's our challenge:

In some cases, the original customer/recipient forwards their campaign email to a colleague and when that colleague responds via email, we are not able to capture that within sfmc. Because they were not the original contact the email was sent out to.

Are there any solutions out there, where we can handle this forwarding situation using any available tools/logic inside sfmc. Any insight would be appreciated!